CSVHelper test parsing against multiple classes with attribute maps
I have a large number of CSV files in multiple formats, all dumped together in one folder.  The naming convention is of no use in determining the type, and there is no identifier within the file other than the columns themselves.  The only test is to see if it successfully maps to one of the mapping classes.
I am using CsvHelper with attribute mapping on all my class properties.
csv.GetRecords<T>() succeeds just fine with the appropriate class for the file and throws an exception (as expected ) when passed an incompatible file and type.
Is there any kind of TryParse method or technique within CsvHelper that can test to see if a mapping will work, or do I need to build a long nested try {} catch {} tree and just keep hammering until one of the classes succeeds?
I'll probably build this out with my own TryGetRecords<T>() but I wanted to see if there was better or built-in way.

An error can only be captured once unless the code where the error is captured uses a THROW.  So if the error is being captured in CsvHelper (or a library) you cannot capture the error again.

CsvHelper throws a HeaderValidationException when the headers don't match.  That's fine.  I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to test if it will pass without actually running the whole file.  But if CsvHelper throws immediately after parsing the headers, without reading all the rows, then perhaps catching that exception is indeed the best way.

There doesn't appear to be a native method in CsvHelper to test a file against a model, but if the headers don't match when mapping it will throw a HeaderValidationException right away without parsing the entire file.
Here's my wrapper:
public static class Csv
{
    public static bool TryGetRecords<T>(string filePath, out List<T> results)
    {
        try
        {
            using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            results = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
            return true;
        }
        catch (HeaderValidationException)
        {
            results = [];
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Which can then be called like:
if (Csv.TryGetRecords(filePath, out List<ModelA> modelARecords))
{
    // do things with List<ModelA>
}
else if (Csv.TryGetRecords(filePath, out List<ModelB> modelBRecords))
{
    // do things with List<ModelB>
}

